# ssh connection over ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

hy 
i try to connect in the new server by ruby script

```
> 1.9.2p320 :038 >  Net::SSH.start('192.168.10.80', 'root', :password => 'xxxxx')
> Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: root
>     from /home/zyriuse/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:215:in > `start'
>         from (irb):38
>        from /home/zyriuse/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

i dont understand why i get this error because when i try manually everything it's working

---

i try a lot of thing

```
require 'net/ssh'
require 'logger'

Net::SSH.start(
   'localhost', 'zyriuse',
   :keys => [ "~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub" ],
) do |session|
puts "hello "
end
```

~
 zyriuse (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed)

```
Net::SSH.start( 'host',
            :password=>'passord', 
            :port=>22,
            :username=>'zyriuse',
   ... ) do |session|
 puts "hello wordl"
end
```

`start': Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed

i dont understand why i get all the time the same error

Comment: dont expose your actual password.

Comment: When you do the `ssh` manually, are you logged in as `root` or are you using `roogt@192.168.10.80` in your `ssh` request?

Comment: so...it fails in rails but not ruby?  what does "non manual" mean here?  What users is it run as for both?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure:

1. The account is correct
2. The password is correct
3. The IP is correct
4. that `ssh root@192.168.10.80` works from your machine, typing the password

The error `AuthenticationFailed` means just that.